# jQuery button click once do this, click twice restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like a button to turn a text element to a certain string and then restart once it is off and make it blank again.
I tried this:

```
$('#checkbox5').on('toggle', function() {
$("#texty5").text("Video/film"); 
$('#checkbox5').on('toggle', function() {
$("#texty5").text(""); 
});
});
```

But it only works the one time you press and unpress it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably only define one "toggle" event callback, and handle both scenarios.

```
$('#checkbox5').on('toggle', function() {
    if ($("#texty5").text() === "") {
        $("#texty5").text("Video/film");
    } else {
        $("#texty5").text("");
    }
});
```